# Error validaing new data while updating gridview row data in asp.net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm creating simple web forms application using asp.net for registering patients data using entity framework.I'm using Dynamic data fields for easy validation of editable data based on Microsoft Sql Server Data types and null allow

[image: Data Table]

My Aspx Code for entity data source and data gridview is

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="WebApplication4.PediatricDbEntities" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Patients" EntityTypeFilter="Patient">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PatientID" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="PatientID" HeaderText="PatientID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PatientID" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="BirthDate" HeaderText="BirthDate" SortExpression="BirthDate" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Sex" HeaderText="Sex" SortExpression="Sex" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
```

CS Code Behind

```
protected void Page_init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EnableDynamicData(typeof(Patient));
    }
```

However when i try to edit data and set field which not allows null to null value an error appear before validation summary appears  as follows
[image]

I want to know how to validate new data while updating data grid view row using dynamic fields .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by setting up `MetadataTypes` against your objects.

As an example with the Name field..

```
  [MetadataType(typeof(PatientMetadata))]
  public partial class Patient
  {
    public class PatientMetadata
    {
      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      ....

    }
  }
```

A walkthrough is available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488549(VS.100).aspx

Comment: According to this tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-8
Dynamic Data functionality can provide the following benefits:
Fields are automatically formatted for display based on their data type.
Fields are automatically validated based on their data type.

So My code above is supposed to work without adding metadata as dynamic fields are automatically validated based on datatype
I only need to add metadata to customize formatting and validation behavior.

Comment: Good point, it's been a while since I used it as I mainly do MVC but when I did I always created the MetaData. I don't remember it automatically working for me.